# How can I validate and parse an ISO 8601 timestamp with user's time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, iso8601

I need to be able to receive a user-input timestamp, with an *optional* time zone component, *validate* that is it a valid ISO 8601 time representation, and parse it according to the *user's configured time zone*.

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 on Ruby 2.3.  I had hoped that `Time.zone` (`ActiveSupport::TimeZone`) would have an equivalent implementation to `Time::iso8601` so that I could rescue `ArgumentError` exceptions to determine if the user input was a valid ISO 8601 time representation.  Then I could do something like:

```
user_time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles' # Would actually be from user's stored settings
params = {when: '2016-04-01T01:01:01'} # Would actually be from user input

# Would actually use Time::use_zone in around_action filter
Time.use_zone(user_time_zone) do
  timestamp = Time.zone.iso8601 params[:when]
end
```

But, alas, no such method exists.  And I can't find an equivalent one.

I can't use `Time.zone.parse`, because it treats ambiguous dates as valid (e.g. `Time.zone.parse '04/11/16' # => Tue, 16 Nov 0004 00:00:00 LMT -07:52`).

The best alternative I've been able to come up with so far is:

```
Time.use_zone(user_time_zone) do
  old_tz = ENV['TZ']
  ENV['TZ'] = Time.zone.name
  timestamp = Time.iso8601 params[:when] # => 2016-04-01 01:01:01 -0700
  ENV['TZ'] = old_tz
end
```

But this is ugly, messing around with an environment variable this way doesn't feel proper, and it and certainly isn't Rails-like.  How can I validate and parse the time according to the user's time zone in a Rails way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you simply split the assignment into two steps: validate the ISO8601 format first and if valid, parse it:

```
user_time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'
params = { when: '2016-04-01T01:01:01' }

begin
  Time.iso8601(params[:when])      # raises ArgumentError if format invalid
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts "invalid time format" 
  return
end

Time.use_zone(user_time_zone) do
  timestamp = Time.zone.parse(params[:when])
end
```

Comment: Actually, your original revision was correct.  The time zone will be taken into account when parsing the time, then it will be represented according to the user's time zone setting, which is correct.  If there is a need to output in a different time zone, #in_time_zone can be used.  Trying to use the regex to distinguish between the two cases makes it messy and error prone (e.g. when timestamp is '2016-04-01T01:01:01Z').

Comment: Aah, thanks, you are absolutely right! I rushed too much with the answer and didn't pay close enough attention to my tests. I also agree that the regex is not ideal and am glad that it's not needed. Deleted the wrong part of the answer.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I needed.  Only other thought is that `begin..rescue` should wrap more tightly around the call to `Time.iso8601` to distinguish from other `ArgumentError`s, such as if an invalid time zone is passed to `Time.use_zone`.

Comment: I agree with every point you make, it was just a quick example from my side, but it is actually better to show the best code possible even in an example. :) I updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can still use an `around_action` for your use case. That's what I use and it works well for me.

In my `ApplicationController` I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  around_action :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    old_time_zone = Time.zone
    Time.zone = user_time_zone
    yield
  ensure
    Time.zone = old_time_zone
  end
end
```

Any calls to `Time` will use the user's time zone within the scope of the request.

Comment: How does this validate or parse a ISO 8601 timestamp?

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were asking *when* not *how*. I would check out the Chronic library. It is very flexible and may work with what you need.https://github.com/mojombo/chronic